# Select where any word in string of column A matches any word in string of column B

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, where-clause

I've been searching the website for some guidance, but I haven't been able to find something that fits. I was wondering if there is a way to select rows where "any word in a string in column A matches any word in a string in column B"? I am using postgresql.

```
ID | Name              | Name_of_kin 
1  | Peter Reeves      | John Reeves
2  | Emily Sanchez     | Roger James
3  | Rico van Der      | Moses van Fel
4  | Monic             | Monica
5  | Michaelangelo     | Michael
```

In this scenario, I want to select rows where any word in `Name_of_kin` matches any word in `Name`. The outcome I am hoping to achieve is:

```
ID | Name              | Name_of_kin 
1  | Peter Reeves      | John Reeves
3  | Rico van Der      | Moses van Fel
```

A big thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn each string to an aray of words and check if they overlap:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where string_to_array(t.name, ' ') && string_to_array(t.name_of_kin, ' ')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8c5e26fa3483e572642a4b2d62c3449d)**:

```
id | name         | name_of_kin  
-: | :----------- | :------------
 1 | Peter Reeves | John Reeves  
 3 | Rico van Der | Moses van Fel
```

In Snowflake, you would write this as:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where array_overlap(split(t.name, ' '), split(t.name_of_kin, ' '))
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: thanks! If that wasn't Postgres, that would be *really* more complicated to do...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This is indeed short and sweet!
I have a question though, is there a way we can do this without using the && operator? My data is connected through snowflake, which doesn't support &&. I tried using intersect but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Do you have the option to submit a raw query?

Comment: @Jeremy: snowflake has different syntax but it seems the same functionality is available with `split()` and `array_overlap()`. I updated my answer.

Comment: A big thank you! I was still trying to look through the documentation for a parallel syntax but you got it out so quickly. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular expressions:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.name ~ ('(\W|^)' || replace(t.name_of_kin, ' ', '(\W|$)|(\W|^)') || '(\W|$)');
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where ' ' || t.name || ' ' ~ (' ' || replace(t.name_of_kin, ' ', ' | ') || ' ')
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.name ~ replace(t.name_of_kin, ' ', '|') and
      t.name_of_kin ~ replace(t.name, ' ', '|');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=23f84ec8ea71c0a6bcb50f2d6576e46c) is a db<>fiddle.